# Correr mi app de vue cli desde el index.html

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, cordova, spa

Hola hace unos dias e tratado de compilar mi app de vue con cordova, y resultado fatal. Me puse a investigar y resulta que la razon por la que no carga mi sitio es porque cordova (al igual que ElectronJS) no corre un servidor web interno, sino que sirve los archivos usando el protocolo file:///.

Entonces me genero una duda, acerca de como hacer para que mi app de vue al iniciar el index de la carpeta `dist` corra en un servidor http.

Lo que intente fue cambiar todos mis `href=/etc` a `href="./etc"` para darle un formato html sin procesamiento. Pero debido a unos ajustes con mi router de vue no me corre la ruta. igualmente mi app esta configurada como pwa, y debido a eso no me regitra el serviceWorker. Me sale este error en consola:

```
Error during service worker registration: TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The URL protocol of the current origin ('null') is not supported.
    at s (index.js:75)
    at index.js:57
```

Al correr un servidor en localhost si me funciona todo a la perfeccion.

¿Alguna sugerencia?